# Rotativa footer image doesn't work

Tags: c#, rotativa

It returns empty pdf without any content

```
string customSwitches = string.Format( "--header-right \"text\" --footer- html {0}",
         Url.Action("Footer", "Competition", new { area = "" }, "http"));

return new ActionAsPdf("Pdf", new { compId = compId, personId = personId })
{
    //FileName = "Report.pdf",
    CustomSwitches = customSwitches
};
```

View

```
<div style="text-align:center;font-size:11px;border-top:2px solid black;height:20%;padding-bottom:300px">
   <img style="width:12px" src="~/images/e_lg.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: do you have an action called "Pdf" ? If yes, what does it return?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put this on your view:

```
src="@Server.MapPath("~/images/e_lg.jpg")"
```

Comment: a little explanation would help